# Switch case function opens just the last item

Tags: java, android, webview, navigation

Hi I have a Navigationmenu which works with an switch case function. The Header group components are defined with an "i". The submenu component are defines as "il". I'am trying to open a submenu, but it opens just the last defined link on item 3. Why the submenus opens just the last link? And where is my error? Please help!

Thats the function:

```
prepareListData();
        mMenuAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, expandableList);

        // setting list adapter
        expandableList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {
                //Log.d("DEBUG", "submenu item clicked");

                switch (i) {
                    case 0 :
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/");
                        break;

                    case 1 :
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/news/");
                        break;

                    case 2 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/iphone/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/ipad/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/mac/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/appletipps/");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/ios-apps/");
                                break;
                        }

                    case 3 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/smartphones/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/tablets/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/androidtipps/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/android-apps/");
                                break;
                        }

                    ...


                return false;
            }
        });
       ....
```

Comment: debug your code, if none of the set sub-values are taken by the inner switch, it'll go waterfall to the next cases. Even then, the breaks you do have there, are for the inner switches, not for the outer one

Comment: Have you checked `i1`' value? If so, does it have a value `!= 4`?

Comment: the outer switch for case(s) 2 to 7 are missing the break clause

Comment: Your  case 2,3 ,4, 5,6, 7 never breaks .

Comment: I did run the debugger. but could not see something. Sorry but iam new on android studio @Stultuske

Comment: @SinanKara you just forgot to add `break` in your  `case  2,3,4,5,6,7` check it

Comment: Switch/case in switch/case is never a good idea!

Comment: @Nilu Thanks! I changed it and it worked :)

Comment: @ADM Thanks! I changed it and it worked :)

Comment: @SinanKara happy to help you

Comment: Do prefer Debugging code before directly posting question here . Thx

Comment: @ADM Iam new on Android Studio and didn't knew that :/ But now I will do it. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `break` statement in your `expandableList.setOnChildClickListener`

the following are some `case` in which your forgot to add `break`

- **`case 2`**
- **`case 3`**
- **`case 4`**
- **`case 5`**
- **`case 6`**
- **`case 7`**

Comment: @SinanKara happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

There is no break statements for the `case 3`, `case 4`, `case 5`, `case 6` and `case 7` when you are checking for '`i`' value. Problem is in these cases, when it will traverse for `i1` and if `i1` does not match any of the nested cases then it will go for next case.

So place `break` after each nested `switch-case` which will solve your problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy that I could able to help you. You can accept the answer or upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `break` after parent cases:

```
 prepareListData();
        mMenuAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, expandableList);

        // setting list adapter
        expandableList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {
                //Log.d("DEBUG", "submenu item clicked");

                switch (i) {
                    case 0 :
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/");
                        break;

                    case 1 :
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/news/");
                        break;

                    case 2 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/iphone/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/ipad/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/mac/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/appletipps/");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/ios-apps/");
                                break;
                        }
                    break;
                    case 3 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/smartphones/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/tablets/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/androidtipps/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/android-apps/");
                                break;
                        }
                    break;
                    case 4 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/windows/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/windows/tablets-windows/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/windows/ultrabooks-windows/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/windows/pc-windows/");
                                break;
                        }
                    break;
                    case 5 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/testberichte/smartphone-testberichte/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/testberichte/tablet-testberichte/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/testberichte/ultrabooks-testberichte/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/testberichte/prozessoren-testberichte/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/testberichte/grafikkarten-testberichte/");
                                break;
                        }
                     break;
                    case 6 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/top20/smartphones/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/top20/tablets/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/top20/ultrabooks/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/top20/prozessoren/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/top20/grafikkarten/");
                                break;
                        }
 break;
                    case 7 :
                        switch (i1) {
                            case 0:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/autos/");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/natur/");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/pflanzen/");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/landschaften/");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/tiere/");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/stadtansichten/");
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/struktur/");
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/technik/");
                                break;
                        }
                    break;
                    case 8 :
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/news/");
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
        expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //Log.d("DEBUG", "heading clicked");
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/");
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/news/");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/apple/");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/android/");
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/windows/");
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/testberichte/");
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/top20/");
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/wallpaper/");
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        webView.loadUrl("http://pixelay.com/ueber-uns/");
                        break;

                }


                return false;

            }
        });
```